# New MacBook Pro 13” screen goes black when opened past vertical

Tags: macbook-pro

My screen goes black when opened past vertical.  Tried all the NVRAM and SMC recommended fixes, but neither have fixed it.  Seems like hardware issue and it seems to be getting worse...

In order to use it, i need to open the screen slowly.  After it passes ~45 degrees each ~15 degrees the screen brightness drops by a little.  Then right around 90 degrees (vertical), it goes black.  To bring it back I have to close it again and open slowly.

When screen first went black on me and problem started (one week ago) I was still able to open to just past 90, now it’s gone down to just under 90 and making it hard to work...

Comment: It's helpful if you include your MacBook model (Pro, Air, etc.), the year, the version of macOS you're running and if/whether you have taken it in for *any* service in the past.  Your symptoms point to either a faulty back light or a bad connection.  It's very uncommon for LVDS connectors to just fail out of the blue and back lights have been known to die.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with MacBook Pro 13" devices that are older, the issue is that the LVDS cable or backlight power cable have begun to fail.

This isn't a software issue and will require a hardware repair. You've not specified how old the machine is, you can do the following to find out:

1. Click the Apple logo in the menu bar.
2. Click About this Mac.

[image]

3. Look here:

[image]

*You could additionally verify this is a hardware fault by connecting an external screen, or projector via the Mini DisplayPort/Thunderbolt or HDMI ports and verify this issue doesn't happen on the external monitor at the same time as the internal one.*

Comment: It's common?  How so?  What data do you have to back that up?

Comment: Personal experience.

Comment: No service appointments previously
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Are these issues that could be caused by corrosion, for example if I was living in a beach town next to the ocean for a year? Would that make the failing LVDS or backlight more likely?  

Thanks so much

Comment: Unfortunately that’s more information that I have but having worked at Apple the hinge was a common point of failure for these cables and would create the symptoms you are describing. Have you tried an external monitor to verify the hypothesis?

Comment: I have the same problem with the same 13" Macbook pro from 2016. I have already sent my laptop to Brea Mall Apple store, the first speculation was to reseat the cable and expect to fix the display, unfortunately it didn't fix the problem (same as I have read from many other online reports). And since the warranty is out, it will cost me $400 to replace with a new display.

Comment: The thing is Apple repair team claims they didn't see enough reports in their system to justify it is a known problem therefore they can't give me any break on the cost. Sad!
I am trying to learn how to get Apple to acknowledge this is a common enough quality issue that hits enough people that they should do something about it.

Comment: 100% LVDS or backlight cable. The reason this occurs, the two mentioned cables pass through the hinges of your machine, from the main board to your display. When you open and close your laptop, they wear out over time. Just like how headphone cables fail at the jack from bending.

Comment: If you bought the product from Apple's online store or an Apple Store you should be able to get Apple Support to cover it under EU consumer law, assuming it was bought within the EU, and that it was for consumer use. However it's a bit of a battle you have ahead.

Comment: Apple has acknowledge that there is hardware issue with some MacBook Pro 13" ~2017. See https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service

Comment: Thank you @MattiasWadman for the link, I needed that before I spent my own money.

Comment: No problem, i got the screen replaced for free after i cited EU consumer law

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with certain models and you could be eligible for a few replacement. See https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service

Also
"If you believe your MacBook Pro was affected by this issue, and you paid to have your display repaired, you can contact Apple about a refund."