# New MacBook Pro screen goes black when opened past a certain angle

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook PRM went black suddenly as it was being used. no reasons. PRAM reset didnt help. When connected to external monitors there is no issue.

The display is good as the lid is opened up to around 80degrees or so. Then it becomes black.  It definitely is a hardware issues
Searching yielded the below & the issue appears to be the same.  Any idea with 15" ? Apple wants to charge 700$ for the same - this laptop was purchase Jan 2017.  Any suggestions?  No extended warranty

[New MacBook Pro 13” screen goes black when opened past vertical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316697/new-macbook-pro-13-screen-goes-black-when-opened-past-vertical?newreg=0aac17f5c36b4d7c91185416d7600885)

Answer (score 1):

There is little doubt this is indeed the same issue as with the 13". Apple changed the screen hinge signal cable design starting from the 2015 MacBook Retina and subsequent MacBook Pros, both 13" and 15", to a design that is more complex and prone to failure from material fatigue. These signal cables often start failing in precicely the way you have experienced after the screen has been opened and closed some hundreds of times. I have replaced many of these screens for this reason, both 13" and 15", they are all susceptible to it, at least up to and including the 2018 models.
For the time being, you are however out of luck with Apple replacing it for free, as they inexplicably only have a repair program for this issue for the 13" 2016 model.

[image: 'Old' screen signal cable to the left, exiting at a right angle from the screen and thus twisting with screen openings. New more complex design to the left, now bending with each opening]
'Old', robust screen signal cable to the left, exiting at a right angle from the screen and thus twisting with screen openings. New more complex design to the left, now bending with each opening

For what you should do, I would get a screen assembly from eBay, for instance this https://www.ebay.com/itm/LCD-Display-New-Space-Gray-2016-2017-A1707-15-MacBook-Pro/254135956738 (presuming you have a Space Gray MBP) and check the '2 year protection plan from Squaretrade' option when you check out, for the very reason that any screen assembly will be vulnerable to this, then get your local 3rd party Apple tech outfit to replace it. I have no association with the eBay seller other than having used them and knowing them for being good and serious.