# Macbook Pro 15" turns black after opening past vertical

Tags: macbook-pro

Im using a MacBook Pro 15" 2017 Touch Bar which is different than this other [MacBook screen goes black when opened past vertical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316697/).

Tried all the NVRAM and SMC recommended fixes, but neither have fixed it. Seems like hardware issue and it seems to be getting worse...

In order to use it, i need to open the screen slowly. After it passes ~45 degrees each ~15 degrees the screen brightness drops by a little. Then right around 90 degrees (vertical), it goes black. To bring it back I have to close it again and open slowly.

When screen first went black on me and problem started (one week ago) I was still able to open to just past 90, now it’s gone down to just under 90 and making it hard to work...

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a hardware problem, and you need to take your Mac to a repair technician.

Comment: I agree. There is no possibility for the OS to check at what angle the display is, therefore it **certainly** is a hardware issue. If you are familiar with such things you can also open the MacBook yourself, but at your own risk obviously.

Comment: The problem is the video cable and/or connector.  It’s hardware issue and you need to take it in for service.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I'll take it in :)

Answer (score 2):

It is an hardware issue. I had the same issue with my MacBookPro 2016, 15 inch touchbar. I took it to a technician and  he fixed it for $180. The problem was with cable which connects board with screen. To technician, apple installed it tight in certain mac models so that it broke when close and open the lid after certain time. Cable should be replaced and left little loose so that it won't break in the future.