# MacBook Pro 2016 screen goes black once it is opened

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware

I have tried all the NVRAM and SMC recommended fixes, but none have fixed it.

I need to open the screen slowly. After it passes ~45 degrees it goes black. To bring it back I have to close it again and open it slowly.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316697/new-macbook-pro-13-screen-goes-black-when-opened-past-vertical?rq=1 - it's probably a hardware [cable fail] issue.